# Spring Boot version update breaks repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

See edit at the end...

I updated the dependencies of an app from 1.5.3-RELEASE to 1.5.9-RELEASE

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mrepo in com.test.svc.TestHandler required a bean of type 'com.test.data.MongoTestRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.MongoTestRepository' in your configuration.
```

My Application.java is at com.test.Application and has the usual stuff:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }   
}
```

My TestHandler is a @Service

```
@Service
public class TestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTestRepository mrepo;

    ...
}
```

My MongoTestRepository is a @Repository interface that operates on MongoTest classes

```
@Repository
public interface MongoTestRepository extends MongoRepository<MongoTest, String> {

}
```

So, with the older version of the spring-boot packages (1.5.3-RELEASE) everything worked fine. Updating to 1.5.9-RELEASE and it builds but gives me the above error on deployment/startup.

What's going on here? Is there some new annotation that I'm missing? Why would a minor version update suddenly break this?

EDIT=I am wrong, it's an update to the spring-data-mongodb package that broke it. It was updated from 1.10.9-RELEASE To 2.0.2-RELEASE at the same time and I didn't notice right away.

Comment: Please show us your MongoRepositroy class?

Comment: MongoTestRepository is there... I mean there's some "findBy" stuff in it but nothing special.

Comment: can you check if this happens also with `1.5.8-RELEASE` ?

Comment: @sfat sorry I made a mistake, it was actually a major version update to spring-data-mongodb. Still not sure why it's happening though. See the edit.

Comment: Because the version you upgraded to is incompatible... You should use the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo` instead of manually adding the `spring-data-mongodb` dependency. That way you will always have a version that is working with your Spring Boot version.

Comment: Yea, I was just digging through the dependencies... looks like you're right